# Unusual struct in c

Tags: c, struct

how should I understand the array of two strings?

```
static struct S1 {
    char c[3], *s;
} s1 = {"abc", "def" };
```

Probably the question is not correct but I have difficulties to understand how it works

Comment: Question title doesn't match question content. What is it you're asking exactly?

Comment: The [C11 6.7.9p14](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) says the null terminator is included only if there is space for it. It's not undefine behavior

Comment: @durnovv any hints where you got this example from?

Comment: @KamilCuk it may be if someone will try to use this array as a string.

Comment: regarding; `static struct S1 {
    char c[3], *s;
} s1 = {"abc", "def" };`  a string is always terminated with a NUL byte. So those 3 byte strings are actually 4 bytes, suggest: `static struct S1 {
    char c[4]; char *s;
} s1 = {"abc", "def" };

Answer (score 4):

`S1.c` has space for 3 bytes and `S1.s` is a pointer to a string.

the first part defines the structure:

```
struct S1 {
    char c[3], *s;
};
```

The next part creates an instance of this type and initializes it with a few values:

```
static struct S1 s1 = {"abc", "def" };
```

static is not part of the struct definition. It refers to the visibility of the instance variable.

Comment: does it mean that S1.c = "abc"; and S1 -> s = "def"; ?

Comment: no, S1 is a type. s1 is an object of the type S1. an object uses a dot (".")to refer to the components. Pointers use the arrow ("->")

Comment: `static` is not part of the structure declaration, it's the variable `s1` storage modifier.

Comment: @KamilCuk, you are right, I clarified that in the answer.

Comment: please clarify what you are missing in the answer, so I can add that. Or accept the answer if you like it (will give the answer an green checkmark)

Comment: `static` affects scope, linkage, and lifetime, not just scope (visibility).

Answer (score 2):

The first initialiser `"abc"` copies those 3 characters into the member `char c[3]`. There is no room for a string terminator so it is a simple array and cannot be treated as a string.

The second initialiser `"def"` copies a pointer into the member `char *s`. It points to the *string literal* `"def"` which is placed in read-only memory. It can be treated as a string but cannot be modified.

Comment: Whether `"def"` is placed in read-only memory is up to the implementation; it is not required by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer `{"abc", "def" }` is not an array. In this context, it is used to initialize an instance of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the same code, but might help to understand what is going on, 1st of all it not array. The structure have 2 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S1 {
    char c[3];
    char* s;   
};

int main(void) {
    struct S1 s1 = { .c = "abc", .s = "def" };
    printf("s1.c: %.*s\n", 3, (char*) s1.c);
    printf("s1.s: %s\n", s1.s);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why array "c" is accessed through pointer? I mean the star in the first print statement

Comment: This answer is C++ code, not C as tagged by the question. But not my DV, since I also posted an answer.

Comment: I don't see anything that isn't `C99`?

Comment: @NeilEdelman That comment was posted before I edited it to be C. It was using `std::string` and `std::cout` before.